# string.Join - "cannot convert from IEnumerable to string[]"

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

Very simple extension method not compiling:

```
public static string Join(this string text, params string[] stringsToJoin)
{
    return String.Join(", ", stringsToJoin.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
}
```

I get "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'"

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5 or earlier? [String.Join Method (String, IEnumerable<String>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) was added in .NET 4.0

Comment: FYI, if you _really_ wanted to make that more robust, you should check to see if `stringsToJoin` is `null`, it can happen. And you should probably use `text` in there somewhere. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) of `String.Join` which accepts an `IEnumerable<String>` was only added in .NET 4.0. It seems you're compiling against an earlier version.

The easiest way to fix this and make it compatible with .NET 3.5 would be to simply call `.ToArray()`:

```
public static string Join(this string text, params string[] stringsToJoin)
{
    return String.Join(", ", stringsToJoin.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                                          .ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5, so that explains it!  Thanks!!