# How to get all words existing after x word count in c#

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to get all the words that exist after the fourth word in a string.

For example

```
private string myText="";
privaate int wordCount ;
private string excessString="";

void IRunOncePerFrame()
{
    // A users can type in a text into a textarea to set the myText of 
myText  = EditorGUI.TextArea(someArea,myText);

//flag to check if someone edited the text
if(GUI.changed)     
 {
// get the number of actual words separated by white spaces, new lines 
wordCount = myText.Split(new char[] {' ','\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;

if(wordCount > 4)
  {
// get all the words that exist after the fourth word and store it in ExcessString
  }

 }
}
```

So if the users writes, "This solves the issue, now time for a drink". All strings after the word 'issue' should be placed in excessString

That is the general portion of the problem which may be helpful to others.

The more personal portion for me is this , I want to take excessString and and make it `excessString = "<color = red>" + excessString +"</color>"` and add it back to myText. **since i do not yet know how to get the words after the fourth word i cant think how to get this done yet**.

Comment: What do you mean "all strings after the word issue"? Is _"This solves the issue, now time for a drink"_ not _a single string_ in your world? Can you clarify what "string" means to _you_?

Comment: Instead of "String" you probably mean "word" i assume?

Comment: Yes, word. will edit

Comment: @John i should have said word. All words the exist after the 4th word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from word 4th till the last one, you can use: `words.GetRange(4, words.Count - 4)`. Then use `Join` to concatenate the result into new string.

```c#
var words = myText.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
if (words.Count > 4)
{
    // get all the words that exist after the fourth word and store it in ExcessString
    excessString = string.Join(" ", words.GetRange(4, words.Count - 4));
        
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I converted words.GetRange(4, words.Count - 4) to an array 
words.GetRange(4, words.Count - 4).ToArray() since the overload requires an array and not list

Comment: @DMDev One of the overrides accept `IEnumerable<string>` so it should accept List<string> too, as List implements that interface. There's an example with List [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join).

Comment: wow , i don't see that override at all, i am looking at them in VS right now and i only see string[] overrides.

Comment: @DMDev I see, this happens when you are using different framework version, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871408/2516718). Since your question was not tagged for specific framework, I've used latest available in my VS.